# PHP echoing in an HTML table

Tags: php, html

i'm new into the PHP programming, and i would need some help from you, how can i do a single table for the information that's received from the data base, or how can i retrieve all the data from the data base at once, without that table being rewrited for each line of information?
This is my code and an image:

```
<?php
  include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mysql connect</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
      $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);

      if ($resultCheck > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {


          echo '<center><table class="table table-dark"><thead><tr><th scope="col">#</th><th scope="col">Nume</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><th scope="row">#</th><td>'.$row['user_last']."</td></tr></tbody></table></center> ";

        }
      }
    ?>

  </body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

[image: The Problem]

Comment: Don't echo the whole table inside the while loop, only the table rows inside the body that repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop only the `tr` not the whole table. like below

```
<?php
      include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
    ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mysql connect</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table class="table table-dark">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Nume</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
          $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);

          if ($resultCheck > 0){
           $i=1;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
              echo '<tr><th scope="row">'.$i.'</th><td>'.$row['user_last']."</td></tr>";
              $i++;
            }
          }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under your while loop try this

```
<th>#</th>
<th>firstname</th>

<?php 
 Echo "<tr>
               <td>{$row['id']}</td>
                <td>{$row['firstname']}</td>
             </tr>";

?>
```

If this does not work try to put semi colon after the index of id and firstname. Hope this will help